# Factorizing sum of two powers.

Tags: prime-numbers

Is it possible to factorize, I'm trying to prove  it isn't prime.

$x^4 + 15^x$

If for what values of x will the above be prime, also any general method of determining if a really large number is prime?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be factorised, but note that $2^4 + 15^2 = 241$ is a prime.  As others have pointed out, if $x$ is odd, then so are $x^4$ and $15^x$ and hence their sum is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely not a prime-- any odd value of x spoiling it.

Answer (score 0):

As user 'ashley' has pointed, any odd number would damage it. To check the primality in general, there is a deterministic polynomial time algorithm. Please refer the famous  [paper](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf) which proves constructively to check if a number is prime or not is polynomial-time solvable. I don't know if something specific can be made to comment about your problem though.